# Spring Data @Query from application.properties

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How can I take a query from application.properties in Spring Data?

OrderRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, UUID> {

    @Query("#{app.queryExample}") // TODO the query should come from application.properties
    Set<Order> findByExampleQuery();

}
```

application.properties:

```
app.queryExample=select o from Order o
```